# NIntegrate throwing a non numerical error

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to simulate the Fresnel diffraction and hence tried to define that function using `NIntegrate`. Even after using `_?NumericQ` it gives "evaluated to non numerical value error":

```
F[x_?NumericQ, ζ_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
  (Exp[ I*2000*(((0.006)^2 + ζ^2)^(0.5) + (20^2 + (x - ζ)^2)^(0.5))]
  ) / ((0.006)^2 + ζ^2)^(0.5) // Evaluate
, {ζ, -0.003, 0.003}
] // Evaluate
```

What's the way out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined function `F[x_?NumericQ, ζ_?NumericQ]` but never passed `x` as numeric value. (you are using numerical integration after all). In addition, `ζ` is your integration variable. So this can not be a number you pass to integrate.

Try

```
f[x_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[(Exp[I*2000*(((0.006)^2+ζ^2)^(0.5)+
         (20^2+(x-ζ)^2)^(0.5))])/((0.006)^2+ζ^2)^(0.5),{ζ,-0.003,0.003}]
```

Now `f[5]` gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]